# How to overwrite data with PySpark's JDBC without losing schema while writing to RDS posgtres?

Tags: database, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-rds

I am using the code below to achieve the above functionality:

```
   df.write \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("url","some_url") \
            .option("dbtable", "schema.table") \
            .option("user", "db_user_name") \
            .option("password", "pwd") \
            .option("truncate", "true") \
            .mode('append')\
            .save()
```

I have the following questions:

1. Does truncate = true only work with overwrite
2. Why it does not work with append?

Could someone provide some explanation for this!

Answer (score 1):

Truncating a `db` table that you're appending to does not work, as you're essentially attempting to overwrite your table. A quick browse of https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html for `option("truncate")` shows:

> When SaveMode.Overwrite is enabled, this option causes Spark to truncate an existing table instead of dropping and recreating it. This can be more efficient, and prevents the table metadata (e.g., indices) from being removed. However, it will not work in some cases, such as when the new data has a different schema. It defaults to false. This option applies only to writing.

I assume what you're trying to achieve is a *schema validation* between your `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` and the target `jdbc` table. As per the option description above, this should already be the case for options `truncate=True` and `mode=overwrite`, i.e. the schemas must match.

If you're attempting to change the schema of the target table, your `truncate` option should remain set to `False` and `mode` should be set to `overwrite`.

Alternatively, you can write your own schema validation by wrapping this entire process in a Python function and extracting the schemas from both your `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` and the target `db` table, then comparing them.